# How do I copy stdout and stderr into a log file in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, redirect, ms-dos, pipe

I have a script that I'm running from a command line.  I want the stdout and stderr to be displayed on the screen and also to be copied into a logfile with append.

What is the syntax for this piping/redirection?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
for /f "delims=" %L in ('scriptname 2^>^&1') do @echo %L & echo %L >> log
```

The `for` command iterates over the output lines of the script. The carets escape the characters that follow them. The first `echo` goes to the screen and the second is appended to the file named "log".

Note that Powershell has the `tee` command.

Comment: I was really looking for something a lot more simple than this.  Maybe I shouldn't have used the word "script".  It's a java application that's creating all the output.  So I only need do this for the output of one line.

Comment: @Erick: Can you do it within your java application? If not, then what I posted is probably all CMD is capable of. Your other option is to download one of the `tee` for Windows implementations.